# Run .spec.ts files with karma

Tags: typescript, karma-jasmine

I'm creating a project in Node/ExpressJS using Typescript. I'm trying to run spec.ts files with Karma but it keeps on loading ("Instantiating tests" it says).

I'm running the test from within WebStorm.

> Test Run output

```
/usr/local/bin/node /Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/plugins/js-karma/js_reporter/karma-intellij/lib/intellijRunner.js --karmaPackageDir=/Users/kevin/Developer/*/node_modules/karma --serverPort=9877 --urlRoot=/ --testName=Test
```

> Karma Server output

```
/usr/local/bin/node /Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/plugins/js-
karma/js_reporter/karma-intellij/lib/intellijServer.js --karmaPackageDir=/Users/kevin/Developer/*/node_modules/karma --configFile=/Users/kevin/Developer/*/karma.conf.js
06 11 2017 15:22:04.525:WARN [karma]: Port 9876 in use
06 11 2017 15:22:04.528:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.7.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9877/
06 11 2017 15:22:04.529:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency
06 11 2017 15:22:04.537:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
06 11 2017 15:22:05.752:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket eZBj-sWLsllWuk1tAAAA with id 53965572
```

> Package.json (devDependencies)

```
"@types/jasmine": "^2.6.2",
"grunt": "^1.0.1",
"grunt-contrib-copy": "^1.0.0",
"grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
"grunt-karma": "^2.0.0",
"grunt-ts": "^6.0.0-beta.17",
"jasmine-core": "^2.8.0",
"karma": "^1.7.1",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
"karma-requirejs": "^1.1.0",
"karma-typescript": "^3.0.8",
"load-grunt-tasks": "^3.5.2",
"phantomjs": "^2.1.7",
"requirejs": "^2.3.5",
```

> Generated karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      {pattern: './src/**/*.spec.ts', included: false}
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: false,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

> An example test (test.spec.ts)

```
describe('Test', () => {

    it("should pass", () => {
        let helloWorldString = "Hello World";
        expect(helloWorldString).toEqual("Hello World");
    });

});
```

My file structure is:
./src => all .ts files (this also includes .spec.ts files)
./dist => all .js files (generated from the .ts files with npm run grunt)

Anyone any idea what I'm doing wrong?
I'm not sure if I should be running the .spec.ts files or the .spec.js files, could this be the problem?

Comment: are you using `angular.cli` ?

Comment: Oh good question. Nope, I'm not using the angular cli. This is an expressjs node project (in typescript).

Comment: add your scripts please

Comment: Which scripts do you mean? A test script? (*.spec.ts)

Comment: How are you running test ? Add relevant configuration files too

Comment: I have added an example test (test.spec.ts) to my original question. Relevant configuration files were already added, or did I forget one? I'm running the tests by clicking 'run test' in WebStorm (see: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zr3fw3yfreosjzo/Screen%20Shot%202017-11-06%20at%2015.47.47.png?dl=0).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158327/discussion-between-kevin-and-aravind).